# Sum multiple values in certain rows in a unique formula

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I want to do a formula that multiplies 2 values on each row with the same ID (another value) of the row where the formula is. Like a sumproduct selecting only certain rows (by ID) in the range.

I shared the doc [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FAuPfG8bgxv64Ux2E817DIm6YvNic1YHAAH04FgIiJ4/edit#gid=0) so that you can understand what I need better.
(The formula would be in the column "total" at it should automatically do what it's done in the column B)

Thanks

Comment: Should the formula in E6 be `=G6*F6+F9*G9+F10*G10+F13*G13`? The first *plus* is currently a *times*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a criteria for column E should be sufficient to cancel out the non-matching rows. In B6 use,

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($E$6:$E$13=E6)*($F$6:$F$13)*($G$6:$G$13))
```

Fill down as necessary.